# How to get the passed text and array to php

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a form named as my-form. Inside of it has a 2 textbox and 1 multiple select tag. I'm unable to get all the passed data in PHP.

> textbox1 has a name "tname"
>
> textbox2 has a name "tcode"
>
> multiple select has a name "tsubteam"

I am able to pass all the data but i don't know how to get all the data in PHP

```
    var arr = [];
    $('#tsubteam > option').each(function(){
       arr.push(this.value +","+this.text)
    });
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "modify_team.php",
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;",
       data: `$('#my-form').serialize()+"&id="+getQueryVariable('id')+"&subteam="+JSON.stringify(arr),
       cache: false,
       success: function(data)
       {
          console.log(data)
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxoption, thrownerror)
       {
          alert(xhr.status+" "+thrownerror);
       }
```

**And in PHP:**

```
    <?php
    $tcode = $_POST['tcode'];
    $tname = $_POST['tname'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $subteam = $_POST['subteam'];
    ?>
```

Comment: check in php your $_POST like print_r($_POST,true).

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved the main problem here.

All I did was change the

`dataType: "json"`

into

`dataType: "text"`

And modify the retrieving code of each option tag into

```
 $('#tsubteam > option').each(function(){
item = {}
item["id"] = this.value
item["name"] = this.text
arr.push(item)
});
```

**In PHP:**

```
$tcode = $_POST['tcode'];
    $tname = $_POST['tname'];
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $subteam = json_decode($_POST['subteam'], true);
    foreach($subteam as $k=>$v)
    {
        $subteam_name = $v["name"];
        $subteam_id = $v["id"];
    }
```

**The output of passed data in AJAX**

```
tcode=CMPSS&tname=Compass&id=1&subteam=[{"id":"1","name":"Compass Team A"},{"id":"2","name":"Compass Team B"},{"id":"3","name":"Falcon"},{"id":"4","name":"GPON"},{"id":"5","name":"TTV"},{"id":"6","name":"INFRA"},{"id":"7","name":"OSS"}]
```